# Is rationality the same as instrumentality?

Tags: rationality

Is there a difference between rationality and instrumentality?

I heard somewhere, that instrumentality asks, how we should attain our goals, while rationality asks, why we should attain them. But, if we have a goal, say, going home as fast as possible, then the fastest path would also be the most rational decision. Is every rational agent also instrumentally thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relevant link and quote contrasting instrumental reason with substantial reason.  As you say, practical efficiency can be simply instrumental.  The moral qualities of reasoning require a higher order.

[Max Horkheimer’s Critique of Instrumental Reason and the Domination of Nature](https://ldmac5.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/max-horkheimer%E2%80%99s-critique-of-instrumental-reason-and-the-domination-of-nature/)

> The capitalist system can be seen to have a directly proportionate
>   relationship with instrumental reason. Horkheimer goes beyond this
>   comparison to suggest that the gradual reification – the mastery of
>   nature – has its end in Fascism, however liberal democracy and
>   capitalism were very much the target of the Frankfurt School. The
>   capitalist agent looks to commodify the world toward his/her own ends,
>   primarily the individualistic pursuit of self-preservation.
>   Instrumental reason is the greatest tool in this process. In any case,
>   substantial reason, which guides moral judgements and values, a
>   veritable looking glass into reality and the truth of the world, has
>   in today’s capitalist society become obsolete.